# Safari not updating when I serve my local changes on firebase

Tags: firefox, safari

I am using Firebase to test my website on my localhost. I use `firebase serve` to serve my website up. I open Safari and the previous iteration of my js code is running. I open up Firefox and check out my localhost and viola, my changes are there. Is there something keeping safari from seeing the changes? Does safari save cookies or something?

My website is *very* simply and only reads a few documents from a firestore database. It does not save anything client-side that I've programmed in. I could post my code, but it seem unecessary. It's basically a hello world program with a database.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to post a temporary solution to my question... If you go to "Safari" > "Preference" > "Privacy" > "Manage Website Data..." > search: `localhost` > "Remove", you remove the caches Safari stores.

However, this is not a permanent solution because I can't see a way to stop Safari from storing this data, and it does it at seemingly random times.